# SQL Server Case Statement in Group By

Tags: sql-server

I have to get data hour-wise or day-wise in a SQL Server stored procedure.

To get data hour-wise I would use `Datepart(hh, Datecolumn)` and to get day-wise I would use `Datepart(D, Datecolumn)`.

I am using case statement like

```
 @Hourly = 1 then Datepart(hh, Datecolumn) Else Datepart(D, Datecolumn)
```

but I am getting error as `Datecolumn` not present in `Group by` clause

Can anyone suggest how I can handle this without writing two separate blocks like

```
If @Hourly=1
    Select Datepart(hh, Datecolumn)  
    from Table 
    Group by  Datepart(hh, Datecolumn)
Else
   Select Datepart(D,Datecolumn) 
   from Table 
   Group by Datepart(D, Datecolumn)
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire SQL statement?

Comment: What version of SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Case Statement` like this in `Group by`

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN @Hourly = 1 THEN Datepart(Hour, Datecolumn)
            ELSE Datepart(Day, Datecolumn)
          END 
FROM   Table
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN @Hourly = 1 THEN Datepart(Hour, Datecolumn)
            ELSE Datepart(Day, Datecolumn)
          END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Hourly BIT =1

SELECT CASE WHEN @Hourly=1 THEN Datepart(hh,Datecolumn) ELSE Datepart(D,Datecolumn) END
FROM TableName
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN @Hourly=1 THEN Datepart(hh,Datecolumn) ELSE Datepart(D,Datecolumn) END
```